# Parse and AdMob in One iOS Binary?

Tags: ios, admob, apple-push-notifications, linker-errors, parse-platform

Has anybody been able to compile and link Parse and **AdMob** in One iOS Binary?I get linker errors either from Parse or from AdMob depending on build settings.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

AdMob requires the -ObjC linker flag :"This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category".

Parse has removed the Facebook SDK from its framework which generates the linker errors when the project is compiled with the -ObjC flag that AdMob requires.

I don't know of a way around AdMob's dependence on the -ObjC flag.  I'm not a linker guru.

The solution Parse recommends is to add the Facebook SDK to your project.  I don't know of a workaround to this either if you don't plan to use Facebook.

Parse has a support discussion here: https://www.parse.com/questions/i-dont-want-to-use-facebook-in-my-app

*Update*: I tried replacing `-ObjC` linker flag with `-forceload` of the AdMob library.  However, I got the AdMob crash.  It's the same one you get with the missing `-ObjC` linker flag.  Any linker experts know how to replace the `-ObjC` with something that targets only the AdMob library?

*Update 2*: I needed to revisit this after upgrading to XCode 6, iOS 8, and a new version of adMob.  I got it to work by using this `-force_load`:

```
-force_load $(SRCROOT)/.../GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS/libGoogleAdMobAds.a
```

In my case, I have adMob installed inside of subfolders of my project source.  Just substitute ... with your relative path to the adMob SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like following flag solve the problem:

```
-force_load Libraries/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.8.0/libGoogleAdMobAds.a
```